# Meta as prefix meaning?

Tags: meaning

I have come across lots of times with the meta-prefix expressions such as meta-model elements, process-meta-model, metawork etc. I was not able to identify what exactly they mean even with the help of dictionary online.

Please help me with this meta prefix definition. Examples would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, the prefix 'meta-' is often (but not always!) used to denote an element of self-reference. See definitions 2 and 3 at [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/meta-) (use this dictionary with caution).

Here is an example of the prefix being used in this sense concerning models.

> A metamodel is a model that consists of statements about models. Hence, a metamodel is also a model [...]

Example from [Encyclopedia of Database Systems](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_898).